# AsyncCallBack passed as a method parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a method as AsyncCallBack parameter from `Class1` to `Class2` like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void MyTestCallBack()
    {
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        c2.TestCallbackAPM(MyCallBack);//How can i pass MyCallBack method as parameter and use it in class2 as AsyncCallBack?
    }
    public void MyCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
         //....     
    }

}

public class Class2
{   
     public void TestCallbackAPM(/*MyCallBackMethod*/ CompleteRead)//How can i pass MyCallBack method as parameter and use it in class2 as AsyncCallBack?
     {
        string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine (System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "mfc71.pdb");

        FileStream strm = new FileStream(filename,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1024,
        FileOptions.Asynchronous);

        // Make the asynchronous call
        IAsyncResult result = strm.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
        new AsyncCallback(CompleteRead), strm);
     }
}
```

How can I pass `MyCallBack` as parameter from `Class1` to `Class2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the predefined delegate [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return
>   a value.

In your case use `Action<IAsyncResult> callbackMethod` as a parameter to the method - it matches exactly `void MyCallBack(IAsyncResult result)`:

```
public class Class2
{   
     public void TestCallbackAPM(Action<IAsyncResult> CompleteRead)
     {
     }
}
```

If you do not want to use the predefined `Action` delegate, then create your own:

```
public delegate void MyCallBackMethod(IAsyncResult result);
```

The usage is the same:

```
public class Class2
{   
     public void TestCallbackAPM(MyCallBackMethod CompleteRead)
     {
     }
}
```

If you want to pass a method that returns a value, then you can use the predefined [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate.